# Return multiple columns within a data.table while aggregating using .()/list and by

Tags: r, data.table

In the example below, I have a function (`meansd`) that returns the mean of a vector and optionally returns the standard deviation as well. When combining `[.data.table`, the `.`/`list` syntax in `j` and `by` the ideal result that is long on by, but wide on metric (e.g. the mean and sd returned by the function) as shown in the `dcast` result.

Is it possible to get the result of the `dcast` call directly from a call to `[.data.table` similar to `a[, .(meansd(var1, T), meansd(var1, T)), by = bvar]` (and therefore skip the dcast step)? Or does the error from the last example (combining transpose and by) mean I'm out of luck?

```r
library('data.table')

a = data.table(var1 = c(1,2,3,10,123,12,31,4,6,2), bvar = 1:2)

meansd = function(x, sd = TRUE){
  if(!sd) return(mean(x))
  return(list(mean = mean(x), sd = sd(x)))
  
}

#Presumable syntax:
a[, .(meansd(var1, T), meansd(var1, T)), by = bvar] #data are long on metric which is not ideal
#>    bvar       V1       V2
#> 1:    1     32.8     32.8
#> 2:    1  51.8575  51.8575
#> 3:    2        6        6
#> 4:    2 4.690416 4.690416

#What I was hoping the output would be (dcast call results):
ideal = a[, .(meansd(var1, T), meansd(var1, T)), by = bvar]
ideal[, metric := rep(c('mean', 'sd'),2)]
#ideally the output would look something like this, without the need for the dcast:
dcast(ideal,bvar~metric, value.var = c('V1','V2')) #names are nice, but unimportant
#>    bvar V1_mean    V1_sd V2_mean    V2_sd
#> 1:    1    32.8  51.8575    32.8  51.8575
#> 2:    2       6 4.690416       6 4.690416
```

Some related things I've tried:

```r
#some success when only operating on one column:
a[, .(meansd(var1, F))] #returned vector becomes a data.table per `.()` syntax
#>      V1
#> 1: 19.4

a[, .(meansd(var1, T))] #why is this long? Is it possible to be wide? Why does the inclusion of `.()` change it?
#>          V1
#> 1:     19.4
#> 2: 37.47651

a[, .(t(meansd(var1, T)))] #transpose works alright
#>    mean       sd
#> 1: 19.4 37.47651

a[, .(t(meansd(var1, T))), by = bvar] #by does not like a transpose
#> Error in `[.data.table`(a, , .(t(meansd(var1, T))), by = bvar): All items in j=list(...) should be atomic vectors or lists. If you are trying something like j=list(.SD,newcol=mean(colA)) then use := by group instead (much quicker), or cbind or merge afterwards.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you concatenate your two calls to `meansd` into a single vector and *then* transpose it, you'll get 4 separate columns.

Then you just need to clean up by renaming your columns:

```
library('data.table')

a = data.table(var1 = c(1,2,3,10,123,12,31,4,6,2), bvar = 1:2)

meansd = function(x, sd = TRUE){
  if(!sd) return(mean(x))
  return(list(mean = mean(x), sd = sd(x)))
}

a = a[, t(c(meansd(var1, TRUE), meansd(var1, TRUE))), by=bvar]
colnames(a) = c("bvar", "V1_mean", "V1_sd", "V2_mean", "V2_sd")

a
#>    bvar V1_mean     V1_sd V2_mean     V2_sd
#> 1:    1    32.8 51.857497    32.8 51.857497
#> 2:    2     6.0  4.690416     6.0  4.690416
```